# Get element id for nested AddEventListener function when event occurs

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble setting the parameter which JS will get the ID/Name of the element when the event occurs.

```
(function GostoListen() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for (x = 0 ; x < inputs.length ; x++) {
    myname = inputs[x].getAttribute("ID") != null ? inputs[x].getAttribute("ID") : "next" ;
    if (myname.indexOf("My_lnk") == 0) {
        document.getElementById(myname).addEventListener("click", function () {
            getElementById(??????????????).value = "CLICKED";
        }, false);
    }
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the element by using `this`. Within the context of the function you're creating `this` references the clicked element.

See this edited version:

```
(function GostoListen() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (x = 0 ; x < inputs.length ; x++) {
        myname = inputs[x].getAttribute("ID") != null ? inputs[x].getAttribute("ID") : "next" ;
        if (myname.indexOf("My_lnk") == 0) {
            document.getElementById(myname).addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.value = "CLICKED";
            }, false);
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I have tried "this." but with .value too and it didn't work, and was simply .innerText

Comment: @user Great. If this answered your question, please make sure to accept this as the correct answer.